# Razor View Engine: Complex looping with JS

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I am wondering how do I add javascript if condition inside in nested foreach loop expamle:

```
function validation(){
  @foreach (var region in Model.DefaultDeliver)
  {
  //js code
  if(document.getElementByName('#@( region.Region.RegionName)') != null){ 
      foreach (var country in region.Region.Countries)
       {    
          //js code      
          if(document.getElementByName('#@(region.Region.RegionName)') != null){

           }
        }
      } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  How will the js get executed. since razor is server side?

Comment: interesting comment, but the razor will generate the numerous if statements on render.  granted i'm with you that this might be a little smelly.

Comment: @user1603179 might be worth re-evaluating what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the @ before

```
@foreach (var country in region.Region.Countries)
```

If there is compiling confusion between the razor and js you can escape the javascript with

`@:`  (note colon)  for one line

```
//js code    
@:if(document.getElementByName('#@( region.Region.RegionName)') != null){
```

or wrap several with text node

```
@foreach (var country in region.Region.Countries)
    <text>
        if(document.getElementByName('#@(region.Region.RegionName)') != null){

           }

    </text>
```